# Running laika within netbeans with jruby 1.1.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm Ruby/Rails newbie and trying to get the laika tool (http://github.com/CCHIT/laika/tree/master) running within NetBeans IDE. I'm getting the following exception. I'm using NetBeans IDE 6.5.1, JRubby 1.1.6 and GlassFish V3. Any ideas what might be wrong?

INFO: Jruby version is: 1.1.6

INFO: Starting Rails instances
  SEVERE: Exception in thread "pool-13-thread-1"

SEVERE: C:/Program Files/NetBeans 6.5.1/ruby2/jruby-1.1.6/lib/ruby/1.8/pathname.rb:420:in `realpath_rec':

SEVERE: No such file or directory - No such file or directory - C:/Program Files/glassfish-v3-prelude/glassfish/C: (Errno::ENOENT)

SEVERE:         from C:/Program Files/NetBeans 6.5.1/ruby2/jruby-1.1.6/lib/ruby/1.8/pathname.rb:453:in `realpath'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a problem with the GlassFish. It worked fine with on WEBrick.